# editor with good fortran support

Tags: ide, fortran

Can anyone recommend an editor (or an IDE) with good support for fortran ? Most newer editors I find and try lack language support for it.

Answer (score 4):

[Slickedit](http://slickedit.com/) has Fortran Support. I can't tell how good it is, but given the good support for other langugaes, you should give it a try.

Comment: I can vouch for Slickedit's Fortran capabilities.  That's one slick editor.

Comment: I used SlickEdit for FORTRAN for many years. Spent a day or so fiddling up the syntax file for my installation's particular dialect and was quite pleased ever after. A very competent editor! But at about $300, it ain't exactly cheap.

Answer (score 4):

GNU Emacs has a major mode for `FORTRAN`.
Use `M-x fortran-mode` to switch to this major mode.

I have used this mode a lot and can recommend it.
I used it mostly to write a `FORTRAN` dialect that still requires
punched card format however. 
Support for punched card input was my primary concern and I do not
know much about other `FORTRAN` specific functionality of this mode.

Comment: "punched card format" ?! Do you mean fixed format ?

Comment: Yes, fixed format as opposed to free format.

Comment: I think the answer to "Editor with X support" is always, or nearly always, emacs.

Comment: @docgnome: So you propose sort of an autoresponder, something along the lines of:
s/Editor with (good|excellent)? (\w+) support/Emacs has \2 \3 support. bla bla bla/

;-)

Answer (score 3):

[Vim](http://www.vim.org) has a relatively good fortran support. Maybe a little quirky with syntax highlighting, but otherwise ok.

Answer (score 3):

If you're familiar with Eclipse, the [Photran](http://www.eclipse.org/photran/) plugin may be what you're looking for.

- Upside: it's free, cross-platform, and versatile and you get all the fun plugins that exist for Eclipse (SVN, etc.)
- Downside: If you're not familiar with Eclipse,  getting the build environment sorted out can be a real pain. Plus Eclipse is java-based, meaning it's bloaty, slowish, and has a crapload of options that make configuration and setup a real chore.

That said, it beats the hell out of learning either vi or emacs from scratch. Eclipse/Photran seems to  work fine once you find the magic incantation to get it to compile Fortran. If you're already using make, this is a non-issue; under Windows the prospects are dicier but doable.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a Mac, BBedit is very good.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Ultraedit](http://www.ultraedit.com) (IDM.com, ultraedit.com) daily for many types of programming (F90, javascript, DCL, HTML etc).  Works well. Has good FTP support and great syntax highlighting. Have not use it in conjunction with any Windows or Linux compiler. My OS is OpenVMS.

Ransom Fitch