# How to do Fortran90 code Auto-Completion in Visual Studio 2008 with Intel Visual Fortran Compiler?

Tags: visual-studio, fortran

As we all know that Visual Studio provides well support for C# code auto-completion and IntelliSense.

Now I have Intel Visual Fortran Compiler integrated into Visual Studio 2008, and want to make Visual Studio also provides support of Fortran 90 code IntelliSense!

How to deal with it? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't - see [this thread](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/showthread.php?t=78879) from Intel Software Network. Intel didn't plan on supporting IntelliSense for Fortran then and things haven't changed that much nowadays. Their Fortran editor is even missing basic things like automatic deindentation of `end ...` statement.

I'm not a Windows Fortran user but I would search for a better IDE. How about Eclipse + [Photran](http://www.eclipse.org/photran/)? I think it supports Intel Fortran compiler and provides some nice editing features, including some advanced (for a Fortran IDE) refactoring.

Comment: Mark this answer, because hristo lliev provides a lot of useful information, thanks

Answer (score 5):

A bit late, but you might want to check out [Fortran Code Nav](http://publicwiki.deltares.nl/display/FCN/Home)

It's a (free) addin for Visual Studio (2008, 2010 & 2012) that provides Intellisense for Fortran 90. Additionally it has some 'ReSharper-inspired' jump / search functionality.

I created the tool for some colleagues in my spare time, so it's not production quality, but it should be able to parse most fortran constructs and, as far as I can tell, performs smoothly on larger solutions as well.

Comment: I installed it. First Ctrl-Q tried, first Alt-Q tried, enough for a +1. I guess that after using it I will try upvoting many times (even if it is in vain).

Comment: +1 Dear Tiemen, I really do appreciate your great work. I need to insert the intellisense items in lowercase letters (e.g. INTEGER → integer). would you please let me know if it is possible to add such an option to your Add-in?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly (?) you will look in vain for Intellisense in Fortran.  I don't think that the situation has changed since [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473854/best-fortran-ide) were written.

Me, I use Emacs for all my Fortran writing and editing, Visual Studio mainly for managing Fortran compilations, debugging and the like.

Comment: Quoting from your link: Intel Visual Fortran Composer XE 2011 Update 6 adds support for much of this when used with VS2010.  You can get a list of all procedures, go to definition and find all references, get IntelliSense-like displays of tooltips for intrinsics with argument information, and much more.

Comment: For the life of me I cannot find the statement you say is in the answer I linked to.  I can find no implementation of intellisense for Intel Fortran on my installation, which comprises Intel Composer XE 2012 (and 2013 beta) with MS VS 2010.  Google does not provide a clue to this. I see that no one has challenged Hristo's answer to this question.  But there are at least 2 of you out there who believe that intellisense is (or was) available.  Can you provide a URL to somewhere on the Intel site (or anywhere else) that this is explained ?  I would really like to use this feature.

Comment: Oops, sorry -- this is not from your link, but from the one by @hristo-iliev below, http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/showthread.php?t=78879 -- see reply by Steve Lionel (#20) on page 2. Direct link: http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/showpost.php?p=159076. I don't use MSVS 2010, so no way for me to check.

Comment: Thanks, I've found that and will start investigating.